# How to calculate correlation functions for fermionic operators?

Tags: condensed-matter, fermions, density-operator, correlation-functions

In the paper by Peschel (2003) https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0212631.pdf   How does one derive the following relation:

$$
\langle c_{n}^\dagger c_{m}^\dagger c_{k}c_{l}\rangle = \langle c_{n}^\dagger c_{l}\rangle - \langle c_{m}^\dagger c_{k} \rangle
$$

Where $c_{n}^\dagger, c_{m}^\dagger, c_{k},c_{l}$ are the fermionic  creation and destruction operators at sites $n,m,l,k$ respectively.
How can you justify that according to Wick’s theorem, this property
holds if ρ is the exponential of a free-fermion operator? Where $\rho$ is the density matrix of the eigenstate of the Hamiltonian given by:

$$
\hat{H} = \Sigma_{m,n} t_{mn} c_{m}^\dagger c_{n}
$$

Which make $\rho$ to be equal to $|\psi\rangle \langle \psi |$ with $|\psi\rangle$ being the eigen state of $\hat{H}$.